# Docker image with base image python:3.10-slim-buster apt-get update fails to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, linux, docker, debian

I am trying to build the docker image from this Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# Set uid and gid for sally
ARG sally_uid=2002
ARG sally_gid=2002
# Add user and group entries
RUN addgroup -gid $sally_gid sally && adduser --uid $sally_uid --ingroup sally --system sally
# install any updates
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
......
......
......
```

Console output:

```
[root@lndevk8worker1]# docker build -t supervised:1.0 .
[+] Building 14.4s (8/21)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.21kB                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-buster                                                                                                         2.8s
 => [ 1/17] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-buster@sha256:d2cdc150b518f41cbd252979831fb6f28515aa01eb1b726efd6b16ca70e5656b                                                 6.5s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-buster@sha256:d2cdc150b518f41cbd252979831fb6f28515aa01eb1b726efd6b16ca70e5656b                                                   0.0s
 => => sha256:8fd419aca81cfd3987d61550e700546537628562693bc01acc9f85468f483706 27.14MB / 27.14MB                                                                                   4.4s
 => => sha256:e53683fb464bd118081a539c199f8918d31828d851085907fa5a1c5ee324efb3 2.78MB / 2.78MB                                                                                     1.8s
 => => sha256:ee74efc279b75121e9acdef09d44c4d2771bfadbd1c97035ed3fa5ed8498f650 11.50MB / 11.50MB                                                                                   3.3s
 => => sha256:d2cdc150b518f41cbd252979831fb6f28515aa01eb1b726efd6b16ca70e5656b 988B / 988B                                                                                         0.0s
 => => sha256:370bc98a076db61e9c90996676801ebe962588a8607259fd1b9569d6b707c95d 1.37kB / 1.37kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:8c32b5ef693d5d8cdff269f421bf761c1b3e6a30f6ff6caa707d6f105d33176d 7.91kB / 7.91kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:fa7d106afb002534a9671178956cc59c16b96be796b5ae2a2f6afbcb3dedd068 233B / 233B                                                                                         2.2s
 => => sha256:60b2070aeaf108c1398ea8d65ec30fbc2ad2c207ad3ec7e89becc2bd5945652c 3.35MB / 3.35MB                                                                                     3.7s
 => => extracting sha256:8fd419aca81cfd3987d61550e700546537628562693bc01acc9f85468f483706                                                                                          0.8s
 => => extracting sha256:e53683fb464bd118081a539c199f8918d31828d851085907fa5a1c5ee324efb3                                                                                          0.2s
 => => extracting sha256:ee74efc279b75121e9acdef09d44c4d2771bfadbd1c97035ed3fa5ed8498f650                                                                                          0.4s
 => => extracting sha256:fa7d106afb002534a9671178956cc59c16b96be796b5ae2a2f6afbcb3dedd068                                                                                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:60b2070aeaf108c1398ea8d65ec30fbc2ad2c207ad3ec7e89becc2bd5945652c                                                                                          0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 109.48kB                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [ 2/17] WORKDIR /sally-supervised-fe                                                                                                                                           3.4s
 => [ 3/17] RUN addgroup -gid 2002 sally && adduser --uid 2002 --ingroup sally --system sally                                                                                      0.6s
 => ERROR [ 4/17] RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get -y dist-upgrade                                                                                              1.0s
------
 > [ 4/17] RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get -y dist-upgrade:
#0 0.836 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
#0 0.836   403  Forbidden [IP: 199.232.106.132 80]
#0 0.876 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
#0 0.876   403  Forbidden [IP: 199.232.106.132 80]
#0 0.925 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
#0 0.925   403  Forbidden [IP: 199.232.106.132 80]
#0 0.929 Reading package lists...
#0 0.944 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
#0 0.944 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 199.232.106.132 80]
#0 0.944 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 199.232.106.132 80]
#0 0.944 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
#0 0.944 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 199.232.106.132 80]
#0 0.944 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   8 |     RUN addgroup -gid $sally_gid sally && adduser --uid $sally_uid --ingroup sally --system sally
   9 |     # install any updates
  10 | >>> RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  11 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get -y dist-upgrade" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

I was able to successfully build the image last week. This problem started occurring today. I executed: `docker system prune` before building the image also but without any luck.

Any help to overcome this problem is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I assume there are many reasons. Here my solution:

Recently I had the same problem. It seems docker uses itself to build images. In my case I disabled bridge networking (just because I didn't need it, and it made simpler my firewalls). But so, after restarting docker, I was not able able to build my image (timeout during retrieval of Debian packages list, as in your case).

After restoring the normal settings (so allowing bridge network), and restarting Docker daemon things worked again as expected.  Note: you should also check the firewall rules (important for bridge network).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Firewall is disabled and I disabled bridge network. Restarted docker service. It didn't work.

Comment: Now i edited my answer. It was not clear (I hope now it is better): you should enable again the bridge mode (if you modified the docker configuration), and you should restart docker. But probably there are many more reasons. Try to just use the base image without "RUN", and enter to the image, and try to debug the network (which it is difficult because base image has nearly no tools).

Comment: Hi @Giacomo Catenazzi, you were right. For me, it was my organization's VPN that was blocking the repo URL: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease. Once they added exception for this URL, I was able to build the docker image. Many thanks. Cheers.